# Publish SOAP endpoint while using Spring WS

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, soap, spring-ws

I have a couple of WSDL's and to implement SOAP services I am going with the Spring-WS. I am looking for a way to publish the URL's in Spring similar to the EndPointImpl that is available in Apache CXF.

https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxws/EndpointImpl.html